# Time in dropdown list must be after time in other dropdown list

Tags: excel

In Excel I have a drop-down list in cell A2 for the start time of a shift, which contains half hourly increments from 9AM to 9PM (in hh:mm format i.e. 09:00, 09:30, 10:00 etc). In B2 I have a drop-down with the same set-up for the finish time of the shift. This is repeated seven times in the sheet to create a working week in cells C2 and D2 etc.

What I am trying to achieve is if the user selects 12:00 in A2 for the start of a shift, the drop-down list in B2 removes all times up to and including 12:00, so that the shift must end at at least 12:30, and not before the shift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a data validation rule formula utilising `OFFSET` and `MATCH` to achieve this:

Assuming your list of times is in range `H1:H25`

Validation rule (list) for cell `A2` is simply range `=H1:H25`

Validation rule (list) for cell `B2` is

```
=OFFSET($L$1:$L$25,MATCH(A2,$L$1:$L$25,0),0,25-MATCH(A2,$L$1:$L$25,0))
```

Copy cell `B2` to `C2:G2`  which will copy and update the validation rule.

The `OFFSET` returns a part of the validation range where time is greater than the preceeding cell.